# Using esky (and cx-freeze) with static files

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I'm attempting to use [Esky](https://github.com/cloudmatrix/esky) to update and freeze a python application. However, part of the application includes static files.

The way Esky appears to behave, is it creates a second .exe outside of the folder which contains all the python libs and static data I'm including.

When I run the exe from the folder itself, everything works fine, but when I run the 'bootstrap' exe esky creates, it can't find the static data (as it's not in the same relative place).

I suppose I could hard code the folder esky creates, but I can't imagine that's the best way to go about it.

Anyone have any helpful tips/tricks/solutions?

**Edit: Included folder structure from esky docs**

```
prog.exe                     - esky bootstrapping executable
appdata/                     - container for all the esky magic
  appname-X.Y.platform/      - specific version of the application
    prog.exe                 - executable(s) as produced by freezer module
    library.zip              - pure-python frozen modules
    pythonXY.dll             - python DLL
    esky-files/              - esky control files
      bootstrap/             - files not yet moved into bootstrapping env
      bootstrap-manifest.txt - list of files expected in bootstrap env
      lockfile.txt           - lockfile to block removal of in-use versions
      ...other deps...
  updates/                   - work area for fetching/unpacking updates
```

Comment: What is `sys.executable` inside your frozen program? Does it change when running from esky's bootstrap?

Comment: i have static files that esky finds fine when using the boot strapper without doing anything special.